# How to sum the hours and minutes with different items checkin/checkout

Tags: php, codeigniter

We have a table called:

- activities

Each row has this values:

- id
- type (checkin/checkout)
- start (varchar 2020-11-30 15:45)

Given a specific day like 11-30-2020, assuming we have several checkin/checkouts how to sum hours and minutes from these day?

That's the function we tried to get the sum for all day:

```
 function sum_all_hours_by_day($fxemploye_id, $day){
    $core_settings = Setting::first();

    $hours = 0;
    $date = date_create($day);
    $date_format = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');

    $date_format_start = $date_format .  " 00:00";
    $date_format_end = $date_format . " 23:59";

    $options = array('conditions' => array('fxemploye_id = ? and start >= ? and start <= ?', $fxemploye_id, $date_format_start,$date_format_end));
    $activities = FxemployeHasActivity::all($options);

    $i = 0;
    $d1 = 0; //Checkin
    $d2 = 1; //Checkout
    foreach(array($activities) as $ibd){

        $date1 = $ibd[$d1]->start;
        $date2 = $ibd[$d2]->end;

        $timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
        $timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);


        if($timestamp1 == true && $timestamp2 == true){
            $sum = abs((int)$timestamp2 - (int)$timestamp1)/(60*60); 
            $hours = $hours + $sum;
        }
        $d1 = $d1++;
        $d2 = $d2++;
        $i++;
    }


    return $hours;
}
```

Comment: never ever store a timestamp as a `VARCHAR`. This is exactly what the `TIMESTAMP` column type is for

Comment: Having said that, please show us what you've tried, why and where you're stuck. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, reprodcible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved on the one way, i don't think it's the best way to do that, but assuming the database structure is giving as it, it works as a function. If someone can perform that it will be welcome.

```
  function sum_all_hours_by_day($fxemploye_id, $day){
    $core_settings = Setting::first();


    //You can debug forcing the $day = '2020-11-19';
    $date = date_create($day);
    $date_format = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');

    //Adding the time as we don't have that from database
    $date_format_start = $date_format .  " 00:00";
    $date_format_end = $date_format . " 23:59";

    $options = array('conditions' => array('fxemploye_id = ? and start >= ? and start <= ?', $fxemploye_id, $date_format_start,$date_format_end));

    //Getting all checkins between two days as a range
    $activities = FxemployeHasActivity::all($options);

    //We get the $d1 as a first checkin 2020-11-19 08:15
    //We get the $d2 as a first checkout 2020-11-19 13:14

    $i = 0;
    $d1 = 0; 
    $d2 = 1;
    $hours = 0;
   foreach($activities as $ibd){

        $date1 = $aActivities[$d1]->start;
        $date2 = $aActivities[$d2]->end;

        //Convert tot timestamp
        $timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
        $timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);


        //That's the formula where we can now the range between two dates in seconds
        $sum = abs((int)$timestamp2 - (int)$timestamp1)/3600; 
       
        //Sum that for the next
        $hours = $hours + $sum;

        //Move to the next checkin/checkout in the array $activities
        $d1 = $d1 + 2;
        $d2 = $d2 + 2;
        $i++;
    }

    //Return in hours
    return $hours;
}
```

As we have that as float of hours like 5.88 we have to convert to hours and minutes, we can do that with that:

```
 <?php echo sprintf('%02d:%02d', (int) $time, fmod($time, 1) * 60); ?>
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after can be achieved very easily in MySQL itself (assuming you are using MySQL):

```
SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) - UNIXTIMESTAMP(end))
FROM activities
WHERE `start` > X and `end` < y AND fxemploye_id = N
```

And then using QueryBuilder in Codeigniter this would look like this:

```
$db = $this->db;
$db->select('SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) - UNIXTIMESTAMP(end)) as Result');
$db->where('start >',$date_format_start);
$db->where('end <',$date_format_end);
$db->where('fxemploye_id',$fxemploye_id);
$data = $db->get('activities')->result_array();
```